# Wordpress/PHP - options for showing user that chosen username is taken

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, forms, validation

I have a wordpress site where I've created a custom HTML registration form. I"m using PHP in the functions file that creates the user in our WP users table and emails us with the info from the form. Everything works great, but we want a new way of showing the customer if the username is taken. I have it currently working, we're testing it with the username testUser which exists. If we try to register with it and hit submit, it goes to an index page that says it already exists and then redirects the customer back to the form to fix it. We'd like to have an option that lets the customer know this before even submitting, but I'm a novice with AJAX calls and I've had troubles. I'm hoping there's another way. This is the current snippet of working code:

```
if (username_exists($user)){

echo 'Username already exists. Please wait while we redirect you back to the form';
    die("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\"/>");


}

if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
   $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
   if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
       //user has been created
       $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
       $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );

       wp_mail( $to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);


       //Redirect
       wp_redirect( 'http://www.dev.smithhonig.com/thank-you' );
       exit;
   } else {
       //$user_id is a WP_Error object. Manage the error
   }
}


}
add_action('init','create_account');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a user that username is already taken or available you do need to make an ajax call with the desired username the user is typing.. the steps to do this will be like

1. Detect when there is a change in text field used to enter username in your registration form.
2. Send ajax request to check if the typed username is available.
3. Check response of ajax call.
4. Show a message to user if username is available or not.

Place this code in `functions.php` of your theme

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_verify_username', 'check_username' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_verify_username', 'check_username' );
function check_username(){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if( username_exists( $username ) ) {
        echo $username . ' already taken.';
    }else {
        echo 'Hurray ' . $username . ' is available.';
    }

    exit;
}
```

the `add_action('wp_ajax_verify_username', 'check_username')` will add a hook that checks if an ajax call is made with `action` parameter set as  `verify_username`, if so, it'll be handled by the function `check_username` in your `functions.php` which we've written below the hook.

`check_username` function checks the value of `username` variable sent with the ajax call and checks if the username already exists using WP function `username_exists()` and then prints the appropriate response for ajax call.

The ajax call can be made using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#username').on('change', function(){
        let user = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<WP_AJAX_URL_HERE>',
            data: {action: 'verify_username', username: user},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                // Write code to show the message to user here
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Replace the `<WP_AJAX_URL_HERE>` with your websites admin-ajax.php url

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need more explanation. :)

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and let you know! Much appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry, the only confusion I have is the WP-AJAX_URL line, where would I find that URL for a wordpress site?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/ajaxurl-not-defined-on-front-end/190299 this might help

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I found the Url and put it in the code. I put the function code in but does the Ajax call get pasted in functions.php file as well? I keep getting an error on the third line there for the 'let' object.

Comment: `let` is Ecma Script syntax try using `var` instead.